# date and time separately , a day behind?

Tags: swift, date, datepicker, swift4

Am trying to implement date and time separate selection in my app in 12 hrs format. but for some reason I cannot select current date after initial selection ie I set current date at the start with both label containing time and date separately. The current date and time initially set is correct but later when I change the date to previous date and select current date after that , the formatted date is coming a day behind even after setting current locale.

The date and time are initially set like this :

```
func setDateandTime() -> SubmitReportDate{

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "submitReportDate") as! SubmitReportDate
    let dateFormatter : DateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale.current
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy"
    let date = Date()
    if(userInstance.userData?.Date != nil){
        self.date = (userInstance.userData?.Date)!
    }else{
        self.date = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
    }
    cell.dateLabel.setTitle(self.date, for: .normal)
    let timeFormatter : DateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    timeFormatter.locale = NSLocale.current
    timeFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
    timeFormatter.amSymbol = "AM"
    timeFormatter.pmSymbol = "PM"
    if(userInstance.userData?.Time != nil){
        self.time = (userInstance.userData?.Time)!
    }else{
        self.time = timeFormatter.string(from: date)
    }
    cell.timeLabel.setTitle(self.time, for: .normal)
    cell.dateLabel.addTarget(self, action: #selector(dateChanged(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    cell.timeLabel.addTarget(self, action: #selector(timeChanged(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    return cell

}
```

Here the date and time after formatting displays correctly.
Then to change date this function is what I use.

```
@objc func dateChanged(sender: UIButton){

    let alert = UIAlertController(style: .actionSheet, title: "Select date")
    alert.addDatePicker(mode: .date, date: Date(), minimumDate: nil , maximumDate: Date()) { date in
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy"
        dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale.current
        self.date = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
        self.userInstance.userData?.Date = self.date
        self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(item: 6, section: 0)], with: .none)
    }
    alert.addAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel)
    alert.show()

}
```

Here is where I change my time:

```
@objc func timeChanged(sender: UIButton){
    var maxDate = Date()
    if (userInstance.userData?.Date != nil) {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy" //Your date format
        dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale.current
        //dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT") //Current time zone
        let date = dateFormatter.date(from: ((userInstance.userData?.Date)!))
        if(date! >= maxDate){
            maxDate = date!
            let alert = UIAlertController(style: .actionSheet, title: "Select Time")
            alert.addDatePicker(mode: .time, date: maxDate, minimumDate: nil , maximumDate: maxDate) { date in
                let timeFormatter = DateFormatter()
                timeFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
                timeFormatter.amSymbol = "AM"
                timeFormatter.pmSymbol = "PM"
                self.time = timeFormatter.string(from: date)
                self.userInstance.userData?.Time = self.time
                self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(item: 6, section: 0)], with: .none)
            }
            alert.addAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel)
            alert.show()
        }else{
            let alert = UIAlertController(style: .actionSheet, title: "Select Time")
            alert.addDatePicker(mode: .time, date: maxDate, minimumDate: nil , maximumDate: nil) { date in
                let timeFormatter = DateFormatter()
                timeFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
                timeFormatter.amSymbol = "AM"
                timeFormatter.pmSymbol = "PM"
                self.time = timeFormatter.string(from: date)
                self.userInstance.userData?.Time = self.time
                self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(item: 6, section: 0)], with: .none)
            }
            alert.addAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel)
            alert.show()
        }

    }else{
        let alert = UIAlertController(style: .actionSheet, title: "Select Time")
        alert.addDatePicker(mode: .time, date: maxDate, minimumDate: nil , maximumDate: maxDate) { date in
            let timeFormatter = DateFormatter()
            timeFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
            timeFormatter.amSymbol = "AM"
            timeFormatter.pmSymbol = "PM"
            self.time = timeFormatter.string(from: date)
            self.userInstance.userData?.Time = self.time
            self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(item: 6, section: 0)], with: .none)
        }
        alert.addAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel)
        alert.show()
    }
}
```

In both last two functions the date and time are wrongly set. The whole logic of this code is to limit the time to current time if the date is set as equal to or greater than current date and if it is less than current date no limitations occur in time.

Answer (score 1):

Your time update code should also be updating self.date to the corresponding value.

Separately, I'd suggest splitting out your code to do the date picker work - the result would be a lot more readable, and hence easier to comprehend and debug.